# Rails JSON API with Devise - PUT requests log user out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, cancan

I'm trying to simply update a record using a JSON API on a rails site. dev site here: [vitogo.org](http://www.vitogo.org). I'm using `CanCan` for authorization and `Devise` for authentication.

Using [POSTman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) I can make a GET request just fine, but when I try to make a PUT request, it just loggs me out of the site.

I've been searching for a while and can't find an answer that solves my problem. I believe this to be related to not having a CSRF token when making a PUT request from a JSON API, so I tried adding:

```
before_filter :verified_request?

def verified_request?
    if request.content_type == "application/json"
      true
    else
      super()
    end
  end
```

I assume a lot of people do this, so I don't know why I haven't been able to find an explanation for how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer here was that I was sending the wrong JSON. With POSTman I was just giving a `key value pair`, when I need to do `model[key]:value`. so in my situation, to update my name in the user model, I needed to do:

`key: user[name] value: Dave.`

The above example would change my name from Arel to Dave. What it did was change the JSON being sent from `{"name"=>"Dave", "id"=>"39"}` which is wrong, to `{"user"=>{"name"=>"Dave", "id"=>"39"}}`